# Right gsub regexp entry

Tags: regex, r, sed

Having string like this:

```
 "structure(list(a = 5, f = 6), .Names = c(\"a\", \"f\"))"
```

Where the part

```
 "structure(list(            ), .Names = c(            ))"
```

always stays the same. Entries like x=y inside parentheses and theirs counterparts inside c() are changing both content y, label x, and count as well.

What is the right global substitution, like in sed or R gsub, to get result

```
 "a = 5, f = 6"
```

using only one gsub call?
Ie, everything before and after to go away.

The intention is to get R elipsis content "as it is" like one word and combine it into text in some place in report. So the source comes from "...".

Comment: As usual for regex questions: What do you mean by "string like this"? What can change and what always stays the same?

Comment: Its worth understanding a little more about why you're asking this. That is the output of `dput` and should parse properly in R.  Can you expand on the question?

Comment: My string comes from deparse(list(...)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the solutions:

```
gsub("structure\\(list\\((.*)\\), .*$", "\\1", x)
# [1] "a = 5, f = 6"
```

or equivalently:

```
gsub(".*list\\((.*)\\), .*$", "\\1", x)
```

Comment: I can not reproduce the same result, could you add even line x <- ..., just to see what is happening?